# Need to load HANA table through Spark, with no Spark Vora integration as such

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hana

I have a requirement where I have to load data from Hadoop to SAP HANA. I have already worked with MySql, DB2 and few other RDBMS with Spark and loaded using HSBC Spark Data frame API in version 1.5.0 and above also with Cassandra and Hive but not HANA.

Is it possible to do so without any modifications from the HANA side? (as I can't touch HANA installation in any way)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sqoop, if you prefer to stay on Hadoop side.

SAP BusinessObjects Data Services with Hive Adapter also works fine.

Comment: We already have a file based approach where we are extracting the data from hive and copying it to Hana server and then loading it there using HDBSQL commands. This approach is very length and often not efficient. Sqoop won't help me, can u post give more insights on the SAP Business Objects Data services. There is one constraint we don't have much access to play around with Hana installation so we will have to load it using something externally.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about int he first half of your comment. Sqoop is definitely capable of reading Hive data directly, without prior extraction of it to files (in fact, Hive itself is just an interface, reading organised files from app/hive/warehouse or something like that). Then Sqoop uses JDBC to write data directly to HANA tables. The SAP Data Services path is similar: Data Services reads data from Hive using its Hive Adapter, then writes to HANA using JDBC. Performance is very much the same, and neither of these options requires HANA changes.

Comment: Well there are lot of business constraints involved in the approach, in short my requirements is I need to use spark to process data and load to Hana. This last step of loading data into Hana after processing is the main question here and the main problem I am facing.